# Extract files from folder according to timestamp given in their title using python

Tags: python

I have a folder containing various files which are named using timestamps like this:

```
2016.08.06_09.31.53_test

2016.08.06_09.36.23_test1

2016.08.04_10.41.23_test

2016.08.04_10.46.20_test1
```

I am trying to write a program that can pull out only files from this folder which have a time stamp within a certain time span.
E.g. if the user Input is a Folder Directory and the timespan is 6.8.2016, 9am to 10 pm and the program should give back only the first two files from above. 
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Read filenames into container, sort the container by date in name, return only files in sorted container between given 2 dates. This would be O(n logn) time and O(n) memory.

Answer (score 0):

With the above naming system, it is incredibly simple... Get your files into a list

```
list_of_files = [file1, file2 , ... ]
list_of_files.sort()
print list_of_files
```

That will sort it for you incredibly quickly - the .sort() changes the original list, and puts it into alphabetical order (which here is all you need)